# What is the term used for the opposite of a construct form?

Tags: terminology, hebrew

In many languages (especially Hebrew in which I work), words can appear in a special form called the construct form in which you can expect that word to be attached to another word. I would like to know that what is the term used for the opposite of a construct form? Meaning, a word which is self-standing and independent, and not attached to another word.

Example:
The word צור means rock. 
The phrase צור החלמיש means *chalamish* rock, with the word צור appearing in the construct.

If I had the word צור with the modifier, what is that form of the word called?

Comment: Well, in Hebrew the whole construction is called 'smichut', the modified noun 'nismach', the modifier 'somech'. Sometimes the modified is referred to as 'nomen regens', the modifier as 'nomen rectum'.

Comment: I don't know anything about Hebrew, but "citation form" might be relevant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Semitic linguistics it is customary to refer to the "absolute state" and the "construct state", or their Latin equivalents "status absolutus" and "status constructus".

Comment: It is worth noting that the distinction need not be binary. Aramaic, for instance, also has an emphatic state. (So "opposite" in the question is slightly misleading.)

Comment: @fdb Is the "definitive" state the same as the "absolute" state in linguistics?